# Get full list of host and services from Nagios

Tags: linux, nagios, cgi, microsoft-excel, parse-server

I need to get a full list of hosts and services from Nagios, to make a decision table.

I think there is two methods, querying the Nagios CGI, and parsing the Nagios cfg files.

But... Nagios cfg files may not be standard and this could be a problem.

Anyone knows how do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scrape this out of the object cache file (the path of which can be found in nagios.cfg, typically located somewhere like `/usr/local/nagios/var/` or `/var/cache/nagios3/`), or scrape it out of the HTML output from the CGI (which you can run via the command line), but why reinvent the wheel?

You might want to try [pynag](http://pynag.org/), as it's made for exactly this purpose. If Python isn't your style, there's also the [API category on Nagios Exchange](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/APIs) that has similar add-ons to expose this info in almost any format you can imagine.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer [MK Livestatus](http://mathias-kettner.com/checkmk_livestatus.html) for this.  You could also use NDOUtils to put this data in a database.

Comment: Another excellent choice